# Convert string serialized version of python bytes back to bytes

Tags: python, byte

I have a byte string stored as a regular string.
For example: byte_str = "b'moose'"

Would like to convert this to a python bytes object. What is the best way? Thanks!

Comment: `eval`. But you *should fix whatever is doing this to begin with*. Just using `str` on an object **is not serialization**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `ast.literal_eval()` is much safer than `eval()`.

Comment: @MattDMo we don't know if security is a concern here (e.g., the string is from some untrusted input). But if it is, sure, then you can use `ast.literal_eval`. Regardless, this is almost certainly a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). For example:

```
from ast import literal_eval

byte_str = "b'moose'"
print(byte_str)
# "b'moose'"
actual_bytes = literal_eval(byte_str)
print(actual_bytes)
# b'moose'
```